What does the animated bar in Visual Studio Test Explorer indicate?
In Visual Studio's Test Explorer window, there is a an animated bar that moves left to right. What does this indicate? Intuitively it feels like it should be indicating that tests are running, but that's not the case:


Probably the most significant thing it represents is the "Test Discovery", but also when the build starts on a test project that hasn't been built yet I believe it also begins to animate.  Once the tests start to actually execute, it becomes a "standard" left-to-right progress bar.
Here is a .gif of the bar going left to right with the information label changing indicating what it is doing:

I can't tell exactly, but in your screenshot, you seem to be missing this information label (maybe your Test Explorer window is too small?)

What tool did you use to create the animated gif and blur out some of the (top secret) information?

@PiersMyers screen to gif. https://www.screentogif.com/
